# AngulasJS - Error when adding additional controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting the following error when I try to add an additional controller. I have one controller named "main" and I'm trying to add an additional controller "posts".

When I add the "posts" controller, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/$injector/modulerr?p0=flapperNews&p1=Err…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.19%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A139)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:36(anonymous function) @ angular.js:3857q @ angular.js:325e @ angular.js:3823dc @ angular.js:3763c @ angular.js:1415cc @ angular.js:1430Xc @ angular.js:1343(anonymous function) @ angular.js:21773a @ angular.js:2549(anonymous function) @ angular.js:2822q @ angular.js:325c @ angular.js:2821
```

app.js

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router'])

// Set routing/configuration
// ------------------------------
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',

    // Set state providers
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {$stateProvider

        // Home state
        .state('home', {
          url: '/home',
          templateUrl: '/static/home.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })

        // Posts state
        .state('posts', {
          url: '/posts{id}',
          templateUrl: '/static/posts.html',
          controller: 'PostsCtrl'
        })

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
    }
])


// Posts factory
// Factories are used to organize and share code across the app.
// ------------------------------
.factory('posts', [function(){

    // create new obect with array of posts
    var o = { posts: [] };
    return o;

}])


// Main controller
// ------------------------------
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'posts',

    // Main scope (used in views)
    function($scope, posts){

        // array of posts
        $scope.posts = posts.posts;

        // Add post function
        $scope.addPost = function(){
            // prevent empty titles
            if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { 
                return;
            }
            // push new post to array
            $scope.posts.push({title: $scope.title, date: new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10)});

            // reset title
            $scope.title = '';
        };
    }

]);

// Posts controller
// ------------------------------
.controller('PostsCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'posts',

    // Main scope (used in views)
    function($scope, $stateParams, posts){
        // body
    }

]);
```

I've been following [this](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/#angular-routing-adding-a-new-state) tutorial, and they recommend using the ui.router, so I'm not sure if this has something to do with it?

If I add the app name before declaring the controller, the routing works fine but then I get another error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: flapperNews is not defined(anonymous function) @ app.js:43
angular.js:9959Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.19/ng/areq?p0=MainCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
```

Comment: You have a `;` before the Posts controller comment followed by  a `.`. Try removing the semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `;` before `.controller` which is breaking the chain

```
]); /* <===  remove ";" */

// Posts controller
// ------------------------------
.controller('PostsCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'posts',
```

you might be better off using the full syntax of :

```
angular.module('flapperNews').controller ...

angular.module('flapperNews').factory ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `;`

```
    // Posts state
    .state('posts', {
      url: '/posts{id}',
      templateUrl: '/static/posts.html',
      controller: 'PostsCtrl'
    }) ; // <---

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
```

Comment: missing before a line break won't throw error though unless it gets minified that way